# How to add drawn feature to existing feature group and output whole as geojson?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have standard draw control, with markers enabled. On `draw:created` :

```
var lr = e.layer,
    latlng = lr.getLatLng(),
    coords = [];
coords.push(latlng['lng']);
coords.push(latlng['lat']);

lr['feature'] = {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: coords
    },
    properties: {}
}

newFeatures.addLayer(lr);
active.addLayer(lr);
openPopup(lr);
```

And on form submit I send stringified geojson to the server:

```
var geoJSON = active.getGeoJSON();
mapInput.val(JSON.stringify(geoJSON));
```

---

Issue:

In `geoJSON` there's no new features, although I see them in console, in `active` layer. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of overcomplicating this. The `L.FeatureGroup` you're using inherits the `toGeoJSON` method from `L.LayerGroup` which returns a `FeatureCollection` based on the current contents of the layer.

> Returns a GeoJSON representation of the layer group (GeoJSON FeatureCollection).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-togeojson

```
var featureCollection;

var featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: featureGroup
    }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
    featureCollection = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/Hfmxfy4iSEgc2Ncu7VJM/preview

Comment: Are we on the same page? You create new geojson object, but I'd like to have all features in one geojson file. `active` feature group has other features already loaded from file. I ended up with:     `var layerGeoJSON = active.getGeoJSON();
        var newFeatGeoJSON = newFeatures.toGeoJSON();
        $.each(newFeatGeoJSON.features, function(index, feat) {
            layerGeoJSON.features.push(feat);
        });`

Comment: Personally i find asking people if they're on the same page a bit weird when you post a three line question, missing all sorts of relevant code. I gave you the best example i could give given the information you posted. That it doesn't meet your expectations is not my fault but yours because you posted a very thin question. I just added the instanciation of a FeatureLayer to the example just to be complete. I can't guess from here that you're working with a existing FeatureLayer. Can't make that up out of the question. I'de recommend reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't meant to be rude, and surely never meant to criticize your answer. I wasn't aware that this synonym is offensive. I rather wanted to ensure that I understand well your answer. Sorry for that, thank you for trying, anyway! I'll try to improve my question.

Comment: This is SO, posting better questions gets you better answers ;) And the community prospers. Still happy you solved it. No worries, good luck with your project